# How do I properly set up anchor links in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm pretty new to Vue.js and Frontend Development in general, so this question might seem dumb to some veterans, but I just can't wrap my head around how to set this up.

My first approach was to just hard code the HTML and use jQuery to scroll to each anchor:

```html
<div class="col-md-4" id="pageContent">
  <div class="sub-nav">On this page</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="anchorLink" data-anchor="Link-1">Link 1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="anchorLink" data-anchor="Link-2">Link 2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$('.anchorLink').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + $(this).data('anchor')).offset().top
    }, 200);
    return false;
})
```

which would have been fine, but somehow this only works after I reload the page and since this approach is not really dynamic I decided not to waste more time on this and build a Vue component for this element which looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="pageContent">
    <div class="sub-nav">On this page</div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="anchor in anchors" :key="anchor._id">
        <div class="anchorLink" :data-anchor="anchor.link">
          {{ anchor.name }}
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    anchors: {
      name: String,
      link: String,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And passed the date like this:

```html
<template>
  <h2 id="Test-1">Test 1</h2>
  ...
  <h2 id="Test-2">Test 2</h2>
  ...
  <page-content :anchors="anchors" />
</template>

<script>
import PageContent from "@/components/PageContent.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    PageContent,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      anchors: [
        {
          name: "Test 1",
          link: "Test-1",
        },
        {
          name: "Test 2",
          link: "Test-2",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

This works for now, but now I'm pretty much stuck with the same problem, I have to reload the page each time for the jQuery script to work. I'm really lost right now, and I don't really know how to progress at this point, since I don't know what the "best" way of doing this would be. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: what do you mean by *have to reload the page each time for the jQuery script to work*? where is the jquery code put?

Comment: fyi you should replace the `$('.anchorLink').click(function () {` with a `@click=""` on the element

Comment: I've actually managed to solve the issue just based on your hint with the @click handler, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="btn-primary" @click="scrollToAnchorPoint('testBlock')">
    Scroll Test
</a>
<div ref="testBlock">
    In page anchor point
</div>
<script>
export default{
    methods: {
        scrollToAnchorPoint(refName) {
            const el = this.$refs[refName]
            el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'})
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

[forsmile.jp](https://forsmile.jp/en/vue-en/1118/)